# When is the soonest I can Close my window?

Tags: c#, c, wpf, windows

I perform some checks in my Window class constructor, and if they fail I want to display an error message and close the window.

I'm getting crashes when calling Close() from the constructor or from Window_Loaded.  Does that sounds normal or am I doing something wrong?  If this is normal, when should I call Close()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out you can call Close() in the constructor or on Window_Loaded - I was just doing something wrong later on in the destructor.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend performing those checks before showing the window and if they fail, then display the error.  In other words, don't show the window unless it's ok to do so.